# Show that the partition of $G$ into conjugacy classes is a refinement of the partition of $G$ into cosets of $G'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G'$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$. Show that the partition of $G$ into conjugacy classes is a refinement of the partition of $G$ into cosets of $G'$

I'm not sure how to break $G$ into cosets of $G'$ and then create a refinement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "breaking $G$ into cosets of $G'$ and then creating a refinement" - the partition of $G$ into cosets of $G'$ is determined by $G'$, so there is nothing to ''do'', and you don't get to choose the refinement. You are trying to show that a given partition of $G$ (that of $G$ into conjugacy classes) is a refinement of another partition of $G$ (that of $G$ into cosets of $G'$ in $G$). It seems to me you might be confused about what you're trying to show, so here is some clarification.

The point is this: you want to show that for any $g \in G$, the conjugacy class $C(g)$ of $g$ is a subset of some left coset of $G'$ in $G$. Concretely, let $g \in G$; since the trivial conjugate of $g$ (namely $g$) belongs to $gG'$ and distinct cosets of $G'$ in $G$ intersect trivially, you want to show that $C(g) \subset gG'$, i.e. every conjugate of $g$ belongs to $gG'$.

To this end, note that for any $z \in G$, $zgz^{-1} = g[g^{-1}, z] \in gG'$, which proves the claim.

Comment: This is correct (except for the typo $z\in g$ in the last line, which should be $z\in G$), but it would  be simpler to note, in the second paragraph, that $gG'$ is a (and therefore the) coset of $G'$ containing $g$. Then, you can use $g$ in place of $h$ in the rest of the proof, and you can dispense with $k$ and $l$.

Comment: Dear @AndreasBlass: thanks for your insightful comment. I've amended the answer accordingly.